# Jquery .prop('currentSrc') not finding the srcset property on <picture> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use `.prop('currentSrc')` to get the *current* srcset (depends on browser size) of an image that is being shown.

However, Jquery doesn't seem to be able to get the value of srcset from the html `<picture>` element in the code below. The value of newBackground keeps coming back undefined.

Can jquery use .prop('currentSrc') to get the currently used srcset from the picture element? If not, is there a better way?

```js
var photos = $("picture").toArray();
window.setInterval(changePhoto, 6000);

function changePhoto() {
  photos.push(photos.shift());
  var newBackground = photos[0];
  console.log(newBackground); // logs <picture> element
  newBackground = $(newBackground).prop('currentSrc');
  console.log(newBackground); // logs undefined
  $(".banner").css("background-image", "url(" + newBackground + ")");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 901px)" srcset="oldmanfull.jpg">
  <source media="( (min-width : 515px) and (max-width : 900px) )" srcset="oldmantablet.jpg">
  <img src="oldmantablet.jpg" />
</picture>
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 901px)" srcset="hatman.jpg">
  <source media="( (min-width : 515px) and (max-width : 900px) )" srcset="hatmantablet.jpg">
  <img src="hatmantablet.jpg" />
</picture>
```

Comment: I believe only an [`img`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) element has a (potential) `currentSrc` property, not a [`picture`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement).

Comment: Also, a `picture` element is supposed to have an `img` element as one of its children: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add an `<img>` element to your `<picture>`. This is the actual image which will be displayed, and its src attribute specifies a fallback image, in case none of the `<source>` tags work for a particular device.

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 901px)" srcset="oldmanfull.jpg">
  <source media="( (min-width : 515px) and (max-width : 900px) )" srcset="oldmantablet.jpg">
  <img src="fallback_image.png"></img>
</picture>
```

Second, the `currentSrc` element is on `<img>`, not `<picture>`, since the `<picture>` element works by dynamically setting the `src` of its child `<img>`. So your jQuery selection should dig for the `<img>` tag itself:

```
$('picture>img')
```

With those corrections, this code should work:

```
var photos = $("picture>img").toArray();
window.setInterval(changePhoto, 6000);

function changePhoto() {
  photos.push(photos.shift());
  var newBackground = photos[0];
  console.log(newBackground); // logs <img> element
  newBackground = $(newBackground).prop('currentSrc');
  console.log(newBackground); // logs undefined
  $(".banner").css("background-image", "url(" + newBackground + ")");
}
```

And it may be worth mentioning that `currentSrc` is a plain javascript property, so you can easily access it without jQuery:

```
newBackground = newBackground.currentSrc;
```

Comment: tested...that just pulled the src of the img tag inside the picture element each time.

Comment: @Luke that may be because none of the sources were compatible with your test device. I created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4th96up/15/) where I changed one source to "screen," and that source was shown as currentSrc.

Comment: @Luke also, you may need to add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>` to your `<head>` to make media queries work properly.

Comment: oh yeah had that head tag in there already...good call on getting the srcset from the img